# Next.js window is not defined while using useEffect

Tags: javascript, next.js

It looks like next.js 13 tries to execute some script code server side some times while I need it client side.
At the moment I try to use bulma calendar https://doc.mh-s.de/bulma-calendar/

If I import the necessary library in the module:

```
import PasswordStrengthBar from 'react-password-strength-bar';
```

And then even if I use `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('HERE WINDOW:', window, bulmaCalendar);
    bulmaCalendar.attach('#calendar', {});
}, []);
```

I will have `ReferenceError: window is not defined`.

```
file:<...>/node_modules/bulma-calendar/dist/js/bulma-calendar.min.js (1:208)
```

What is interesting I have this error on full page refresh in development mode and the line `console.log('HERE WINDOW:', window, bulmaCalendar);` is not executed. But if I change something in the source file to force the fast refresh everything works well, till I refresh the page in the browser and have that error again. If there is no line `bulmaCalendar.attach('#calendar', {});` the error doesn't happen (while the initialization obviously also doesn't happen). It seems that import is not executed due some optimization if I don't use the `bulmaCalendar` in the code, but when I add `bulmaCalendar` some initialization code is executed during import server side that require the `window` object.

I also tried to use `next/script` to make import from the page client side but seems like it can load scripts only by link and doesn't prepare it for the bundle from `node_modules`. Or the variable `bulmaCalendar` is not accessible after loading in the  tag.

I had possible related problems with some other code to get geolocation on client side.

How can I avoid this problem and force the script to be fully executed client side while don't making some script files manually?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import bulmaCalendar from 'bulma-calendar/dist/js/bulma-calendar.min.js';


const Sample = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('HERE WINDOW:', window);
    bulmaCalendar.attach('#calendar', {});
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      <form>
        <input
          id="calendar"
          type="date"
        />
      </form>
    </main>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/interesting-marco-264zc3?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A20%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A11%2C%22startColumn%22%3A20%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A11%7D%5D

Comment: there is no `window` on the server side, so the easiest thing to do is to just check for ```(`typeof window !== `undefined`)``` and only run your code when that's true

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans According to OP, the issue is in the _import_ of `bulma-calendar` but only happens if they actually _use_ `bulma-calendar` due to some optimization Next does. Very strange! Could you try to share a reproduction of the issue?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I've added some minimal page code

Comment: A codesandbox with the issue could be helpful

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I've added a link to sandbox. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to deal with an import not working during SSR:

1. Stub dependencies:

   I don't like this one, but the idea is to do something like `global.window = {}`. This risks breaking other libraries which check for it.
2. Perform a client-side import:

   This is what I suggest:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("HERE WINDOW:", window);
    import("bulma-calendar/dist/js/bulma-calendar.min.js").then(
      (bulmaCalendar) => {
        bulmaCalendar.default.attach("#calendar", {});
      }
    );
  }, []);
```

The idea is to import `bulmaCalendar` when you need it, and not any earlier (such as during SSR).

[Codesandbox with fix](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cold-dream-yj3xcj?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A13%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A15%2C%22startColumn%22%3A13%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A15%7D%5D) (The CSS is broken here)

Comment: It's a good and simple ideas and I think I will accept the answer. While in this particular case it adds multiple calendars to one input.

Comment: Three calendars is the library's defect. It works well with the default selector.